# A Base for the topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $B$ be a base for the topology $O$ on $X$. How to prove the following properties: (1) For any  $U_1$, $U_2$∈$B$ and every point $x$∈$U_1$∩ $U_2$ there exists a $U$ ∈$B$ such that $x$∈$U$⊂$U_1$∩ $U_2$. (2) For every $x$∈$X$ there exists a $U$ ∈$B$ such that  $x$∈$U$.

Comment: This is the definition of a base for a topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends what your definition of a base $\mathcal{B}$ for a topological space $X$ is. I will assume that your definition is: all members of $\mathcal{B}$ are open and every open set of $X$ is the union of members of $\mathcal{B}$. The latter can also be formulated as: for every open $O$ and for every $x \in O$, there exists some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset O$ (just write $O$ as a union of members of from the base and take one that contains $x$).

Then property (1) follows from the fact that $U_1 \cap U_2$ is open (as members of the base are open, and so is their finite intersection) and so is also a union of members of $\mathcal{B}$, so again: for every $x \in U_1 \cap U_2$ there exists some $U \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in U \subset U_1 \cap U_2$. 
And property (2) follows the fact that $X$ is an open set, in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to be proven, this is how a basis for a topology on a set $X$ is defined. What you can prove is that this topology $\tau$ is indeed a topology on $X$.